# Regex matching last occurrence without lookahead

Tags: regex, grep

I'm looking for a way to match parts of a string using `grep` on Mac OS and as far as I can tell there is no support for Perl regex. I've seen suggestions about installing `ack` and other tools but that's unfortunately not an option.

Example:
I have the following string: 
`"very programming", "much foo", "such, \"bar\""` and want to match `, "such, \"bar\""`, i.e. the last token. The problem is that no matter how I construct the regex it will only match `, "much foo", "such, \"bar\""` since the middle token also starts with `,` (Comma followed by space).

EDIT: Added quotations and commas within the strings.

I'm currently using the regex:

```
, "[a-zA-Z0-9 !@#\$%\^\\&\*()\.,\-\+'"]*"
```

Explaination:

```
, " followed by
A character class containing all valid characters repeated followed by
")
```

Here is an interactive example: http://regexr.com/395id

So I wonder, is there any way to do this with the regex available to `grep`?

Comment: It would help if you showed up the regex you're currently using.

Comment: I added it. Although I don't want to mislead people with a faulty regex

Comment: Okay, what you want to look for is going to be `, "[^"]*"` instead of what you have. `[^"]` matches anything but a `"`, so the match will end at the first `"` it encounters after entering the text in quotes.

Comment: The problem is that the strings within the quotes should be able to contain `"` as well. I'll update with a more complex example. I also added a link to regexr which might show it somewhat clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit tricky but this regex worked for me in my testing on OSX **without using lookaheads or lookbehinds**:

```
s='"very programming", "much foo", "such, \"bar\""'
egrep -o ', "(?:[^"\\]*\\")*[^"\\]*"[^"]*$' <<< "$s"
, "such, \"bar\""
```

#### [Online Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/uC6tC6/1)

Comment: This combined with making sure the input string only contains single quotes and no double quotes seem to seems to have done it.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried any of the below commands, so if any find an error, let me know and I can fix it, or fix it in-line if you have the fix :)

Firstly, I think what you want to use is a line ending `$` character, so that your regex is this:

```
, "[a-zA-Z0-9 !@#\$%\^\\&\*()\.,\-\+'"]*"$
```

Secondly, perl may be installed already on your system (I would be surprised if it wasn't; it's installed on most UNIX systems nowadays), in which case, here's a trick:

```
echo '"very programming", "much foo", "such \\"bar\\""' | \
    perl -p -e 'if (/(, [a-zA-Z0-9 !@#\$%\^\\&\*()\.,\-\+'"]*)$/) { print $1 }'
```

The above command says 'take each line from standard input, and assign the line's value to `$_` (`-p`). then run this perl command on it (`-e`). Voila! perl regex on UNIX.

Thirdly, here are some UNIX-ish regex tools that might help:

`awk` may be your pal here:

```
awk -F' *, *' '{print $3}'
```

That awk command says 'split the string into pieces based on spaces, than a comma, then a space, and print the third field'. This will actually only print `"such \"bar\""`, but that may be all you're looking for.

`sed` is also a good tool:

```
echo '"very programming", "much foo", "such \\"bar\\""' | \
     sed 's/^.*\(, [[:alnum:][:punct:]]*\)$/\1/g'
```

That command says 'Look for the regex we wanted in the entire line, match it, and print it out'. It should print out the `, "such \"bar\""` you're looking for.

`sed` uses "basic" and `awk` uses "extended" [POSIX regular expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html). These aren't just like perl's, but they're pretty close. For example, in the above example i use the `[:alnum:]` and `[:punct:]` POSIX character classes inside brackets, sort of like Perl's character classes, but POSIX. More to the point, these two commands are on most every POSIX system, including Mac.

Side note: you can use [POSIX character classes in perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html#POSIX-Character-Classes), too:

```
echo '"very programming", "much foo", "such \\"bar\\""' | \
    perl -p -e 'if (/(, [[:alnum:][:punct:]]*)$/) { print $1 }'
```

Comment: Thanks for a great in-depth reply :) The first regex doesn't seem to help, since matching the end of the string will still match from the first comma and onwards (See http://regexr.com/395j5). However I'll give the perl stuff a go when I'm at work again tomorrow!

Comment: Forgot to mention, an issue with `awk` is that I don't know how many tokens there are since the strings themselves can contain commas. I'll update my question to add that.